Dot Net Project functionality use in python project using DLL and facing an issue
I want to call the function from dotnet project and then use it in my python project. but still facing an issue.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shared_DynamicPreference'

code is
import clr
clr.AddReference(r'dlls/Shared_DynamicPreference')
from Shared_DynamicPreference.Services import ListingPreferencesServices

the directory structure of dotnet project is working fine
TestProject
  - TestProject
    -bin
    -obj
    -Services
      -Class1.cs
    -TestProject.csproj
  -TestProject.sln

Not working and face error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shared_DynamicPreference'
-Shared_DynamicPreference
    -bin
    -obj
    -utils
        -ConfigurationHelper.cs
        -Extensions.cs
    -VirtualCrud.cs
    -Model
    -ApplicationDbContext.cs
    -OutputModels
       -ListingPreferencesOutPutModel.cs
    -ResponseModels
       -ListingPreferencesResponsePutModel.cs
    -Services
           -ListingPreferencesServices.cs
    -customsettings.json
    -Program.cs
    -Shared_DynamicPreference.csproj
Shared_DynamicPreference.sln

code is in   file ListingPreferencesServices.cs from which I want to use funcntion getListingPreferenceByUserId.
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Shared_DynamicPreference.Data.VirtualCrud;
using Shared_DynamicPreference.Models;
using Shared_DynamicPreference.Models.OutputModels;
using Shared_DynamicPreference.Models.ResponseModels;
using Shared_DynamicPreference.Utils;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace Shared_DynamicPreference.Services
{
    public class ListingPreferencesServices : VirtualCrud<ListingPreferencesOutPutModel>
    {

        public ListingPreferencesServices()
        {
        }
        public ListingPreferencesResponsePutModelNew getListingPreferenceByUserId(int id, int businessId, int serviceId)
        {
            var response = new ListingPreferencesResponsePutModelNew();
            var datalist = new ListingPreferencesResponsePutModelNew();
            try
            {
                var cmd = db.LoadStoredProc("usp_ListingPreferenceByUserId_Get")
                           .WithSqlParam("@id", id)
                           .WithSqlParam("@BusinessId", businessId)
                           .WithSqlParam("@serviceId", serviceId)
                           .WithSqlParamOut("@ErrorCode")
                           .WithSqlParamOut("@ErrorMessage");

                var result = cmd.ExecuteStoredProc<ListingPreferencesOutPutModel>();


                //response.listingPreference = result;
                response.code = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ErrorCode"].Value.ToString());
                response.message = cmd.Parameters["@ErrorMessage"].Value.ToString();
                if (response.code == 0)
                {
                    var titleResult = getcolumnTitlesByBusinessId(businessId, serviceId);

                    // Initialize listingPreference in datalist
                    datalist.listingPreference = new List<ListingPreferencesOutPutModelUpdated>();

                    foreach (var item2 in result)
                    {
                        var titlesData = titleResult.columnsData
                                    .SelectMany(b => b.country).SelectMany(c => c.columns)
                                    .Where(d => d.columnId == item2.columnId)
                                    .SelectMany(c => c.titles).ToList();
                        var defaultTitle = titlesData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.isDefault ?? false);
                        var selectedTitle = defaultTitle ?? titlesData.FirstOrDefault();

                        var columnNamesOutput = new ListingPreferencesOutPutModelUpdated
                        {
                            id = item2.columnId ?? 0,
                            columnId = item2.columnId ?? 0,
                            columnName = item2.columnName,
                            //columnTitle = item2.columnTitle,
                            position = item2.position,
                            isShown = item2.isShown ?? true,
                            hasOption = item2.hasOption ?? false,
                            isSticky = item2.isSticky ?? false,
                            columnStatus = item2.columnStatus,
                            entityId = item2.entityId,
                            isAdmin = item2.isAdmin,
                            isBusiness = item2.isBusiness,
                            isDeleted = item2.isDeleted,
                            createdBy = item2.createdBy,
                            createdOn = item2.createdOn,
                            modifiedBy = item2.modifiedBy,
                            modifiedOn = item2.modifiedOn,
                            options = new List<ListingOptionOutPutModel>(),
                            columnTitle = selectedTitle.columnTitle ?? string.Empty
                            //titles = titleResult.columnsData
                            //        .SelectMany(b => b.country).SelectMany(c => c.columns)
                            //        .Where(d => d.columnId == item2.columnId)
                            //        .SelectMany(c => c.titles).ToList()
                        };

                        // Add options if hasOption is true
                        if (item2.hasOption == true)
                        {
                            var uniqueOptions = new HashSet<int>();

                            foreach (var item4 in result)
                            {
                                if (item4.columnId == item2.columnId && item4.optionId.HasValue && item4.optionId != 0)
                                {
                                    var optionId = item4.optionId.Value;
                                    if (!uniqueOptions.Contains(optionId))
                                    {
                                        var optionparms = new ListingOptionOutPutModel
                                        {
                                            id = optionId,
                                            optionName = item4.optionName,
                                            optionDescription = item4.optionDescription
                                        };

                                        // Add the option record to the column's options list
                                        columnNamesOutput.options.Add(optionparms);

                                        // Add the optionId to the set of unique option IDs
                                        uniqueOptions.Add(optionId);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            columnNamesOutput.options = null;
                        }

                        datalist.listingPreference.Add(columnNamesOutput);
                    }

                    // Copy listingPreference from datalist to response
                    var filtereddata = datalist.listingPreference.GroupBy(item => item.columnId).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();

                    response.listingPreference = filtereddata;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Set listingPreference to null if code is not 0
                    response.listingPreference = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.code = -1;
                response.message = ex.Message;
            }
            return response;
        }
        public ColumnsTitleResponseModelNew getcolumnTitlesByBusinessId(int id, int serviceId)
        {
            var response = new ColumnsTitleResponseModelNew();
            var datalist = new ColumnsTitleResponseModelNew();
            try
            {//usp_columnTitlesByBusinessId_Get
                var cmd = db.LoadStoredProc("usp_columnTitlesByBusinessIdNew_Get")
                         .WithSqlParam("@id", id)
                         .WithSqlParam("@serviceId", serviceId)
                         .WithSqlParamOut("@ErrorCode")
                         .WithSqlParamOut("@ErrorMessage");

                var result = cmd.ExecuteStoredProc<ColumnsTitleOutputModel>();


                //response.listingPreference = result;
                response.code = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ErrorCode"].Value.ToString());
                response.message = cmd.Parameters["@ErrorMessage"].Value.ToString();
                if (response.code == 0)
                {
                    datalist.columnsData = new List<ColumnsTitleResponseModel>();

                    foreach (var item in result)
                    {
                        var existingBusiness = datalist.columnsData.FirstOrDefault(b => b.businessId == item.entityId);

                        if (existingBusiness == null)
                        {
                            existingBusiness = new ColumnsTitleResponseModel
                            {
                                businessId = item.entityId,
                                country = new List<countryList>()
                            };

                            datalist.columnsData.Add(existingBusiness);
                        }
                        var existingCountry = existingBusiness.country.FirstOrDefault(c => c.countryId == item.countryId);

                        if (existingCountry == null)
                        {
                            existingCountry = new countryList
                            {
                                countryId = item.countryId,
                                columns = new List<TitleColumnsOutputModel>()
                            };

                            existingBusiness.country.Add(existingCountry);
                        }
                        var existingColumn = existingCountry.columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.columnId == item.columnId);

                        if (existingColumn == null)
                        {
                            existingColumn = new TitleColumnsOutputModel
                            {
                                columnId = item.columnId,
                                columnName = item.columnName,
                                columnStatus = item.columnStatus,
                                hasOption = item.hasOption ?? false,
                                titles = new List<ColumnsTitlesOutputModelNew>(),
                                options = new List<optionDataOutPutModel>()
                            };

                            existingCountry.columns.Add(existingColumn);
                        }
                        var columnTitleExists = existingColumn.titles.Any(t => t.id == item.titleId && t.columnTitle == item.columnTitle);

                        if (!columnTitleExists)
                        {
                            existingColumn.titles.Add(new ColumnsTitlesOutputModelNew
                            {
                                id = item.titleId,
                                isTitle = item.isTitle,
                                columnTitle = item.columnTitle,
                                isDefault = item.isDefault ?? false,
                                isBusiness = item.isBusiness,
                                isAdmin = item.isAdmin,
                                isShown = item.isShown ?? false,
                                isActive = item.isActive ?? true
                            });
                        }
                        if (item.hasOption == true)
                        {
                            var optionExists = existingColumn.options.Any(o => o.optionId == item.optionId);

                            if (!optionExists)
                            {
                                existingColumn.options.Add(new optionDataOutPutModel
                                {
                                    optionId = item.optionId ?? 0,
                                    optionName = item.optionName,
                                    optionDescription = item.optionDescription
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    response.columnsData = datalist.columnsData;
                }
                else
                {
                    response.columnsData = null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.code = -1;
                response.message = ex.Message;
            }
            return response;
        }


    }
}


